# How can I play gtalk rtp payload data for video using codec h264?

Tags: rtp

I deal with rtp packets of gtalk video. I want to make video using gtalk rtp payload data. According to my search gtalk use h264 codec for video.

I combined all of rtp payload which is send with gtalk video and wanted to play ffplay using this comment "ffplay -f h264 "filename" but I can't see

anything and I take this error "Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264, yuv420p)". I think my wrong is combining rtp payload. how can I play this payload?

Thanks for your helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need the sequence and picture parameters sets (SPS and PPS) which are often transferred during session setup. Standard protocols used for this are RTSP and SIP though I have no clue whether gtalk uses either of these.